# Change global array when I press a button

Tags: javascript

When I press, the code runs but the array pcs[5] isn't changing. Anybody knows why? The Array is global

```js
function ausfuehrenbutton() {
  var aktion = document.Aktionsformular.aktionen.options[document.Aktionsformular.aktionen.selectedIndex].value;
  pcs[5] = false;
  if (aktion == 1) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
      var tmp = i + 1;
      if (document.getElementById("PC" + tmp).checked) {
        pcs[i] = false;
      } else {

      }
    }
  } else if (aktion == 2) {

  } else if (aktion == 3) {

  } else {

  }
}
```

```html
<form name="Aktionsformular">
  <select name="aktionen">
    <option value="">Aktionen</option>
    <option value="1">Ein</option>
    <option value="2">Zwei</option>
    <option value="3">Drei</option>
  </select>
  <input type="button" onclick="ausfuehrenbutton()" value="Ausführen" />
</form>
```

Comment: A bit more context would be nice. What is your end goal with the code? What is `pcs`? How do you know that it doesn't change?

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add relevant HTML

Answer (score 0):

When you call ausfuehrenbutton() you set pcs[5] to false regardless of what its value was before. If it was false before calling the function it will not have changed ...

Answer (score 0):

it will never change - you have only 4 buttons - and in the array they create the last index is pcs[3]  so you never rich pcs[5]

Answer (score 0):

Not seeing the HTML I guess this will give you some hints to continue

NOTE if you want only the checked boxes, you can change to
`[...document.querySelectorAll("[id^=PC]:checked")]` but then pcs[5] may fail if less than 6 boxes are checked

```js
let pcs = [];
document.getElementById("ausfuehrenbutton").addEventListener("click", function() {
  const aktion = document.getElementById("aktionen").value;
  pcs = [...document.querySelectorAll("[id^=PC]")].map(chk => chk.checked)
  if (aktion == 1) {
    pcs[5] = false; // set to false regardless - this is PC6 by the way
    console.log(pcs);
  } else if (aktion == 2) {

  } else if (aktion == 3) {

  } else {

  }
});
```

```html
<form id="Aktionsformular">
  <select id="aktionen">
    <option value="">Aktionen</option>
    <option value="1">Ein</option>
    <option value="2">Zwei</option>
    <option value="3">Drei</option>
  </select>
  <label>1 <input type="checkbox" id="PC1"/></label>
  <label>2 <input type="checkbox" id="PC2"/></label>
  <label>3 <input type="checkbox" id="PC3"/></label>
  <label>4 <input type="checkbox" id="PC4"/></label>
  <label>5 <input type="checkbox" id="PC5"/></label>
  <label>6 <input type="checkbox" id="PC6"/></label>
  <label>7 <input type="checkbox" id="PC7"/></label>
  <label>8 <input type="checkbox" id="PC8"/></label>
  <label>9 <input type="checkbox" id="PC9"/></label>
  <label>10 <input type="checkbox" id="PC10"/></label>
  <label>11 <input type="checkbox" id="PC11"/></label>
  <label>12 <input type="checkbox" id="PC12"/></label>
  <label>13 <input type="checkbox" id="PC13"/></label>
  <label>14 <input type="checkbox" id="PC14"/></label>
  <label>15 <input type="checkbox" id="PC15"/></label>
  <input type="button" value="Ausführen" id="ausfuehrenbutton" />
</form>
```